# How can I manage margin in basic plot/image in r?

Tags: r, shiny, margin

I made a blank reactive plot with a basic plot, and printed huge characters in shinydashboard.

The problem is that when I made the letters in the plot visible, the margin at the top of the plot is too large.

But when I fixed the margin argument, png size, and list argument in `renderImage()`, the size of margin was fine, but the text is too small and I cannot read the labels anymore. I tried to set the `cex` argument, which worked but not very well. Also, `oma=c()` argument wasn't woriking in my code.

So, what can I do? This is my code about plot.

```
outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')

png(outfile, height=500*25, width=1000, bg='transparent')
par(mar=c(0, 4, 1, 4))
plot(0, 0, xlim=c(1,50), ylim=c(1,500*4), ann=F, xaxt = 'n', yaxt='n', type="n", xlab="")
for(j in 1:500){# i=x, j=y
   for(i in 1:50){
      text(i, 500*4+4-j*4, labels=data0[i+50*(j-1)], cex=2, family='raleway')
   }
}
dev.off()


list(src = outfile, contentType = 'image/png', width=800, height=sizej*15)
```

[image: Huge margin]

[image: Cannot distinguish anything]

Comment: The `png` function has a "pointsize" argument - the default is 12. Try increasing this value. If that doesn't help, try playing with the "asp" argument to `plot`. Your height seems to be much larger than the width. I agree that increasing the height seems to stretch the top and bottom margins, even if you specify 0. But I am not sure why that happens. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE WAY!

I managed margin of the plot with xpd parameter in plot()!
Have a nice day!